# Unexpected End of Expression when used with @Html.Raw(Model)

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use AngularJs with ASP.NET MVC - this is my first attempt.

Index.html

```
@model string
@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="container" ng-init="courses = [{'name':'first'},{'name':'second'},{'name':'third'}]">
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="course in courses">
            <td>{{ course.name }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
@RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

Above works fine and grid is displayed with Name as header and first, second and third as 3 rows. So my next step is to use

```
courses = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
```

instead of

```
courses = [{'name':'first'},{'name':'second'},{'name':'third'}]
```

CourseController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

namespace AngularJsMvc.Controllers
{
    public class CoursesController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Courses
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("Index", "", "[{'name':'first'},{'name':'second'},    {'name':'third'}]"); //This works fine when used with @Html.Raw(Model) in index.html
            //return View("Index", "", GetCourses()); //This doesn't work when used with with @Html.Raw(Model) in index.html
        }

        public string GetCourses()
        {
            var courses = new[]
            {
                new Course { Name = "First" },
                new Course { Name = "Second" },
                new Course { Name = "Third" }
            };
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() };
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(courses, Formatting.None, settings);
        }
    }

    public class Course
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This works fine if I use

```
return View("Index", "", "[{'name':'first'},{'name':'second'},{'name':'third'}]");
```

But if I use

```
return View("Index", "", GetCourses());
```

Then, below is the error I get. Please help - I have been struggling for almost entire day yesterday. I tried with or without Json.Encode

```
angular.min.js:123 Error: [$parse:ueoe] 
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$parse/ueoe?p0=courses%20%3D
at angular.min.js:6

"<div class="container" ng-init="courses = " [{\"name\":\"first\"},{\"name\":\"second\"},{\"name\":\"third\"}]""="">"
```

Comment: How about `return Regex.Unescape(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(courses, Formatting.None, settings));`? JSON.NET escape double quotes in JSON string, hence you need to revert to non-escaped strings first.

Comment: Thanks @TetsuyaYamamoto, tried this just now and same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
<div class="container" ng-init="courses = @Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Model)">
```

This also works:

```
<div class="container" ng-init="courses = @HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model)">
```

It's all about how `angular` treats the object it tries to parse and since you're passing an `HTML decoded string` it will treat as a string and therefore it won't be able to iterate threw it.

Comment: Thanks @Yoav, this worked and I will use it. I am still keen on understanding what is wrong in my approach of "injecting" (so to speak) it from controller method so will leave this unanswered for now.

Comment: Thanks @Yoav, @HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model) also worked.

Comment: Thanks @Yoav still unsure however why in the html courses = @HTML.Raw(Model) doesn't work, but your solution works, thanks.

Comment: @Raoul You may also use \@Html.Raw(Html.AttributeEncode(Model)), I like this b/c you still use the \@Html synthax and it's clear that you are formatting it for HTML purposes (for example it doesn't like the quotations and changes it to html friendly &quot;)